# How to remove gaps between two glass wallls in revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am working on a project in Revit where I need to create four walls, 2 of which are basic wall and the other 2 are glass walls (glass walls are called curtain walls in revit - correct me if I am wrong please). 

I was able to achieve this, but there are some problems with the output.

[image: output]

Following is my code:

Here I get the four points.

```
double width = UnitUtils.ConvertToInternalUnits(2500, DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS); 
double depth = UnitUtils.ConvertToInternalUnits(1200, DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS); 

List<XYZ> corners = new List<XYZ>(4);
corners.Add(XYZ.Zero);
corners.Add(new XYZ(width, 0, 0));
corners.Add(new XYZ(width, depth, 0));
corners.Add(new XYZ(0, depth, 0));
```

Here I draw the wall based on the points.

here levelBottomId is the bottom level

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    Line line = Line.CreateBound(corners[i], corners[3 == i ? 0 : i + 1]);
    Wall wall = Wall.Create(doc, line, levelBottomId, false);
    //add materials to walls to create basic wall or glass wall as per condition

}
```

my code to create basic wall materials is as follows:

```
WallType walltype = wall.WallType;
var newWallType = walltype.Duplicate(wallName)
var compStruct = newWallType.GetCompoundStructure();
 var wallLayers = compStruct.GetLayers();
//add materials
compStruct.SetLayers(wallLayers);
newWallType.SetCompoundStructure(compStruct);
wall.WallType = newWallType;
```

my code to create glass walls is as follows:

```
List<WallType> wallTypeList = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(WallType)).OfType<WallType>().ToList();
WallType walltype = null;
foreach (var wt in wallTypeList)
{
    if (wt.Kind == WallKind.Curtain){
      walltype = wt;
      break;
    }
}
var newWallType = walltype.Duplicate(wallName) as WallType;
wall.WallType = newWallType;
```

1. The walls touch each other leaving no gap, but there is a small gap between 2 curtain walls or between the basic wall and curtain wall. How can I eliminate the gap?
2. Do I have to add another family or something as a connector between
   the glass wall and basic wall or between two glass walls to keep it connected.
3. Is my method to create glass walls correct which might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It looks like your colored arrows should be switched. If you look at your properties panel, it's showing you the highlighted walls on the right are the curtain walls.

Answer (score 1):

Please research the best practices and optimal workflow to solve this problem manually in the user interface before starting to work on the programming side of things.

In general, if a feature is not available in the Revit product manually through the user interface, then the Revit API will not provide it either.

You should therefore research the optimal workflow and best practices to address your task at hand manually through the user interface first.

To do so, please discuss and analyse it with an experienced application engineer, product usage expert, or product support.

Once you have got that part sorted out, it is time to step up into the programming environment.

Here is more advice on [how to research to find a Revit API solution](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3)
.